# What is the algorithm string for 'AGCM256-KW' in java cryptography, to be used in Cipher.getInstance(String algo)?

Tags: java, cryptography, jose4j, jwe

referring [this](https://developer.visa.com/products/vts/guides), I have to encrypt using algorithm **AGCM256-­KW**. I am using Java Cryptography and I didn't find any such algorithm. Closest I found was **AES_256/GCM/NoPadding** but it has no KW (Key wrapping).

here is my test code

```
    public void testEncryption(String algo) {
    String shared_secret = "LyQnklSrxsk3Ch2+AHi9HoDW@//x1LwM123QP/ln";
    try {

        // Step 1 - Create SHA-256 digest of the shared key
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
        byte[] digest = md.digest(shared_secret.getBytes("UTF-8"));

        // Step 2 - generate a 256 bit Content Encryption Key(CEK)
        KeyGenerator kg = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
        kg.init(256);
        SecretKey cek = kg.generateKey();

        // Step 3 - encrypt the CEK using 256 bit digest generated in Step 1
        // and 96 bit random IV. Algorithm should be

        // random 96 bit Initialize Vector
        SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
        // byte iv[] = new byte[96];
        // random.nextBytes(iv);
        byte iv[] = random.generateSeed(96);
        System.out.println("IV: " + toBase64(iv) + " length: " + iv.length);
        IvParameterSpec ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
        GCMParameterSpec gspec = new GCMParameterSpec(96, iv);

        // encrypt
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(algo);
        System.out.println(String.format("CEK Cipher alg:%S provider:%S", cipher.getAlgorithm(),
                cipher.getProvider().getName()));

        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, new SecretKeySpec(digest, "AES"), gspec);
        byte[] result = cipher.doFinal(cek.getEncoded());

        System.out.println(String.format("Encrypted CEK :%S", toBase64(result)));

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**Update 1**
I think I can use [jose4j](https://bitbucket.org/b_c/jose4j/wiki/Home) library which has APIs for [JWE](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-jose-json-web-encryption-40).

Comment: Add expected input/output to your problem statement.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, the Visa Token Services appear to be using JWE (now [RFC 7516](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7516)) so you can use jose4j for this. Here's some sample code that shows encrypting and decrypting some content with JWE using A256GCMKW and AGCM256:

```
    // shared secret hashed to key from your example
    String shared_secret = "LyQnklSrxsk3Ch2+AHi9HoDW@//x1LwM123QP/ln";
    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
    byte[] digest = md.digest(shared_secret.getBytes("UTF-8"));

    JsonWebEncryption jwe = new JsonWebEncryption();

    // A256GCMKW for key wrap
    jwe.setAlgorithmHeaderValue(KeyManagementAlgorithmIdentifiers.A256GCMKW);

    // A256GCM for content encryption
    jwe.setEncryptionMethodHeaderParameter(ContentEncryptionAlgorithmIdentifiers.AES_256_GCM);

    // the key (from above)
    jwe.setKey(new SecretKeySpec(digest, "AES"));

    // whatever content you want to encrypt
    jwe.setPayload("some important content to be encrypted and integrity protected");

    // Produce the JWE compact serialization, which is where the actual encryption is done.
    // The JWE compact serialization consists of five base64url encoded parts
    // combined with a dot ('.') character in the general format of
    // <header>.<encrypted key>.<initialization vector>.<ciphertext>.<authentication tag>
    String serializedJwe = jwe.getCompactSerialization();


    // Do something with the JWE. Like send it to some other party over the clouds
    // and through the interwebs.
    System.out.println("JWE compact serialization: " + serializedJwe);

    // That other party, the receiver, can then use JsonWebEncryption to decrypt the message.
    JsonWebEncryption receiverJwe = new JsonWebEncryption();

    // Set the compact serialization on new Json Web Encryption object
    receiverJwe.setCompactSerialization(serializedJwe);

    // Symmetric encryption, like we are doing here, requires that both parties have the same key.
    // The key will have had to have been securely exchanged out-of-band somehow.
    receiverJwe.setKey(new SecretKeySpec(digest, "AES"));

    // Get the message that was encrypted in the JWE. This step performs the actual decryption steps.
    String plaintext = receiverJwe.getPlaintextString();

    // And do whatever you need to do with the clear text message.
    System.out.println("plaintext: " + plaintext);
```

Comment: Thanks Brian, I have used just that and its simple in comparison to using java cryptography directly.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume you do indeed require AES in GCM mode (I've never heard of AGCM, but I guess this is a logical assumption that it means AES/GCM). Then the following could be used for (un)wrapping a secret key. Note that I didn't get this to work using `IvParameterSpec`, at least not for the Oracle JCE.

```
SecretKey sk = new SecretKeySpec(new byte[16], "AES");
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding");
GCMParameterSpec gcmSpec = new GCMParameterSpec(128, new byte[12]);
cipher.init(Cipher.WRAP_MODE, sk, gcmSpec);
byte[] wrappedKey = cipher.wrap(sk);
System.out.println(Hex.toHexString(wrappedKey));

cipher.init(Cipher.UNWRAP_MODE, sk, gcmSpec);
SecretKey unwrap = (SecretKey) cipher.unwrap(wrappedKey, "AES", Cipher.SECRET_KEY);
System.out.println(Hex.toHexString(unwrap.getEncoded()));
```

Note that using SIV mode should probably be somewhat preferred for wrapping keys as you do do not require to store an IV *and* authentication tag together with the wrapped key (storing the IV is not shown in the example). The above code relies on a unique IV for security (also not shown).

Obviously it's also not a good idea to wrap a key with itself. Sorry, I got a bit lazy here; I've just shown how to use the cipher.

Answer (score 1):

The "KW" refers to "key wrapping," as defined in RFC 3394. The name for this algorithm in the JCE is "AESWrap". So, the transformation should be "AESWrap/GCM/NoPadding". As Maarten pointed out, logically this operation should configure the `Cipher` in `WRAP_MODE`.